# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gz-cmake3"

Tags: gazebo, ros2, colcon

I am running Fortress and Humble and I am getting this error.

```
s@linux-main:~/nookit$ colcon build --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=ON
Starting >>> ros_gz_example_description
Starting >>> ros_gz_example_application
Finished <<< ros_gz_example_description [0.43s]                                
Starting >>> ros_gz_example_gazebo
Finished <<< ros_gz_example_application [0.43s]
--- stderr: ros_gz_example_gazebo                         
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgz-cmake3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "gz-cmake3", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gz-cmake3" with
  any of the following names:

    gz-cmake3Config.cmake
    gz-cmake3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gz-cmake3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gz-cmake3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "gz-cmake3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


---
Failed   <<< ros_gz_example_gazebo [0.32s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 2 packages finished [0.90s]
  1 package failed: ros_gz_example_gazebo
  1 package had stderr output: ros_gz_example_gazebo
  1 package not processed
```

Answer (score 0):

The install [instructions](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz_project_template?tab=readme-ov-file#install) mention switching to the `fortress` branch if you're using Fortress. Otherwise, I think it will assume Garden or Harmonic.